# PHP Roll Call Report

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Below I have the code for a report to be run when a roll call is is required. It will display the person's surname, and the status (In or Out).
I want to be able to have a button in the 1st status column defaulted to OUT (false) so that when it is clicked, that particular row (record) turns a different colour. This is then to update the MySQL database.
The second Status column would have a clear button that will set the colour of the row to white or another colour.
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cardhldr ORDER BY Surname ASC")
or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='5' align='center'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Surname</th><th>Status</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['Surname'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Status'];
echo "</td><td>";   
echo $row['Status']; 
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: So what's your actual question?

Comment: Oh wait i got this: Please Don't use MySQL_* functions as of PHP5.5 they are deprecated, try using PDO instead http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers